# "У слов «Речь Всевышнего»(,) и у слова «Йад» есть 2 значения." Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятые

Вот такой заголовок:

1. У слов «Речь Всевышнего» и у слова «Йад» есть 2 значения.
2. У слов «Речь Всевышнего», и у слова «Йад» есть 2 значения.

Скажите пожалуйста, правильно как в первом варианте (без запятой), или как во втором варианте (с запятой)?

Answer (score 1):

Однородные члены предложения соединены неповторяющимся союзом *и*. Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

По пунктуации — вопрос не основной (союз при перечислении не требует запятой). Ваш заголовок нужно избавить от удлиняющих его повторов и неточностей. Повторения очевидны, а неточность или неправда, содержится в утверждении (так воспринимается) о двух значениях, но их множество у многозначных слов и устойчивых выражений. Для заголовков также нехороша повествовательность полного предложения.

Предложу такой вариант: *О двух из значений «Речи Всевышнего» и «Йада»*.

Comment: Если имеется более двух значений, несколько странно посвящать статью (заметку, параграф) только двум из них. Но даже если так (воля автора), то Ваш вариант звучит неважно. Вариант "О двух значениях" возможен, но он оставляет вопрос об общем количестве значений открытым. Или как-то так:  "О двух из множества значений", "О двух наиболее известных (важных или т.п.)  значениях".

Answer (score 0):

1. Без запятой. Дело в том, что однородные члены предложения соединены единым союзом "и": "козёл и овен", - а в тех случаях, если однородные члены не объединены союзом "и" или перед каждым однородным словом по союзу "и", пишется запятая: "козёл, овен", "и козёл, и овен".